# Replace content of jquery object

Tags: jquery

I have :

```
var tempdiv = "<div><div class='c'>TEST</div></div>";
```

I now need to replace the  `"<div class='c'>TEST</div>"` with `"<ul></ul>"`.

Also, tempdiv is more complex and have many other divs etc.

I tried:

```
$(tempdiv).find(".c").replaceWith("<ul></ul>")
```

This does not work as the result from this gives me `"<div class='c'>TEST</div>"` and not the completly changed `tempdiv`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code replaces the element, but it doesn't change the original string (`tempdiv`). if you want to get the string representation of the wrapper element, you should read it's `outerHTML` property:

```
tempdiv = $(tempdiv).find(".c").replaceWith("<ul></ul>").end().prop('outerHTML');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Please explain ur comment below!

Comment: @BhumiSinghal You are welcome. I'm not sure which part of it is not clear. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Bala Thanks for the edit, but it doesn't seem to be what OP is tying to achieve, it also generates invalid markup, an `ul` with no `li` child.

Comment: @undefined " it seems the second (undocumented) parameter of the replaceWith is the innerHTML of the element" : SO using a normal replaceWith provides the previous innerHTML but what you have done provides the changed outerHTML

Comment: @BhumiSinghal I meant the second parameter of the `replaceWith`'s callback function, the first parameter is the `index` and the second parameter is the `innerHTML` of the element. `this` keyword in the callback refers to the current element (here the `.c` element).

Comment: @Bala but still undefined's answer was correct, didn't it? And you replaced it with actually incorrect one (with `li`)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $(tempdiv).find(".c").replaceWith(function(_,elem){
return "<ul>"+elem+"</ul>";
})
```

### [updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L9NFX/6/)

Comment: This results in `"<ul>[object Object]</ul>"`.

Comment: If i try on my console, then the tempdiv remains unchanged

Comment: I do not have a DOM. tempdiv is actually like this in my code.

Comment: I expected to see the above result, it seems the second (undocumented)  parameter of the `replaceWith` is the `innerHTML` of the element.

Comment: @undefined : please explain your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
$(".c").replaceWith("<[ul](/questions/tagged/ul)>/<[ul](/questions/tagged/ul)>");

Comment: i cant do direct $(".c") as the element is in the var tempdiv

Answer (score 0):

when you call variable, you cant use $ . just call by its name.

```
tempdiv.find(".c").replaceWith("<ul></ul>")
```

or

```
$('.c').replaceWith("<ul></ul>")
```

Comment: `tempdiv` is a string, it doesn't have `find` method and unfortunately "when you call variable, you cant use $" doesn't make sense.